# getElementByID Not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm currently having a problem with a script that calls `getElementByID` in Internet Explorer 11 (and presumably older versions).  It works fine in Edge, Chrome, FF, etc. But in IE, the divs don't appear and in the console I get the error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'visibility' of undefined or null reference

Essentially, there are four hidden divs and the script reveals each one in turn with a few seconds gap between them.

The function is called by the body tag:

```
<body onload="displayBlocks()">
```

Html for the divs is:

Some Text

```
  <div id="text_box_2" class="tb">
    Some Text
  </div>

  <div id="text_box_3" class="tb">
    Some Text
  </div>

  <div id="text_box_4" class="tb">
    Some Text
  </div>
```

And the script is:

```js
i = 0;

function displayBlocks() {
  if (i < 4) {
    alert
    setTimeout(function() {
      showBlock(i);
    }, 3000);
  }
}

function showBlock(blockN) {
  if (blockN == 0) {
    item = document.getElementById("text_box_1");
    item.style.visibility = "visible";

  }

  if (blockN == 1) {
    item = document.getElementById("text_box_2");
    item.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (blockN == 2) {
    item = document.getElementById("text_box_3");
    item.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (blockN == 3) {
    item = document.getElementById("text_box_4");
    item.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  i++;
  displayBlocks();

}
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Another case of "globals are evil"

Comment: I suggest reading up on `var`. You're not using it even once, and that is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the name of your item variable - it is a reserved variable for IE

```js
var i = 0;

function displayBlocks() {
  if (i < 4) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      showBlock(i);
    }, 3000);
  }
}

function showBlock(blockN) {
  if (blockN == 0) {
    console.log(item);
    var item1 = document.getElementById("text_box_1");
    item1.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (blockN == 1) {
    var item1 = document.getElementById("text_box_2");
    item1.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (blockN == 2) {
    var item1 = document.getElementById("text_box_3");
    item1.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (blockN == 3) {
    var item1 = document.getElementById("text_box_4");
    item1.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  i++;
  displayBlocks();
}

displayBlocks();
```

```css
.tb {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="text_box_1" class="tb">
  Some Text 1
</div>

<div id="text_box_2" class="tb">
  Some Text 2
</div>

<div id="text_box_3" class="tb">
  Some Text 3
</div>

<div id="text_box_4" class="tb">
  Some Text 4
</div>
```

If you run the above snippet, you will see it crashes in every browser but IE due to the `console.log(item)`

As @JLRishe points out, you can make your item local to the `if` if you declare it as a var - you seem not to declare any of your variables (you should start to otherwise they are all global and you will run into more of these type of problems)

Comment: OP doesn't need to rename their variable. They just need to use `var`.

Comment: @JLRishe good point, edited answer

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, really appreciate it thanks.

Comment: You're welcome glad we could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` on the end of your code, also you wrote alert but didn't give it any parameters or call it.

Comment: All browsers would throw a syntax error if this was the problem.

Comment: Sorry, alert was a hangover from some testing and the extra } is because on the full page code the script is enclosed in an additional function that checks screen size, I did a bad copy and paste job :)